# How to generate an HTML link automatically from URL in a users' post

Tags: posts, urls, html, front-end, blog

I am using the User Submitted Posts plugin to enable users to put posts on my Blog. I would like to take the URL from the post and convert it into an HTML link with (for example) iframe. Any ideas how I can do this?
Thanks!

Comment: What's the context? When do you need the link? When posts are created you can see their URL when you edit them.

Comment: I would like to embed a map of Google Maps in a blog post such that when the blog is posted you see the map instead of the link.

Comment: I wanted to load HTML links however I prefer to automatically convert the URL into a map. And I would like to enable a user to write a story about the map if that's possible. Thanks!